# How to disable Folder indexing with Apache?

Tags: apache, indexing, vhosts

My vhost on Debian has follwing entry

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

But Apache still shows all the content

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW2Z6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLNoE.png)

Any idea?

Comment: Did you restart apache after edit the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have set the parameter

```html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

inside my 000-default.conf and forgot to enable the Config.